Injecting Context from Android into SqlDelight Driver using koin within KMP
I have a Kotlin Multi-platform project, that has iOS, Android and Desktop in it, and I wanted to use SqlDelight to store data. however I'm using Koin as a DI.
Since I have several platforms, I made the commonMain to startKoin.
This file contains the expect value that will return the SqlDriver for each platform, and rest of the needed implementation to communicate with the database from commonMain.
expect val dbModule: Module

val repoModel = module {
    single<DbRepository> {
        DbRepository(get<SqlDriver>())
    }
}

fun initKoin() = startKoin {
    modules(
        dbModule,
        repoModel
    )
}

I found out that each platform have an Issue, so I decided to focus on one platform at a time.
the problem of the Android platform is that you can't get the context needed for the AndroidSqliteDriver.
actual val dbModule: Module = module {
    single<SqlDriver> {
        AndroidSqliteDriver(Kos.Schema, androidContext(), "Kos")
    }
}

for Android, you need the context to initialize the driver, but you have no way to inject it. since I'm starting Koin from commonMain, I couldn't find a way to get the android context from the Application class.
I tried this way:
class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
        }
    }
}

also this way
class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        koinApplication {
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
        }
    }
}

and even this way
class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        loadKoinModules(
            module { 
                single { this@MyApp }
            }
        )
    }
}

and I always get an error...

Caused by: org.koin.core.error.KoinAppAlreadyStartedException: A Koin Application has already been started


Caused by: org.koin.android.error.MissingAndroidContextException: Can't resolve Context instance. Please use androidContext() function in your KoinApplication configuration.

how is it possible to get android context for SqlDelight driver withing kmp using Koin?

I tried several ways...
the only way it worked for me is to get the context manually into Koin.
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
lateinit var androidContext: Context

actual val dbModule: Module = module {
    single<Context> { androidContext }
    single<SqlDriver> {
        AndroidSqliteDriver(ReminderDb.Schema, get(), "ReminderDb")
    }
}

class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        androidContext = applicationContext
    }
}


Here's a solution that has worked perfectly for integrating an SQL driver into your Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project:
Initialize Koin in Shared Module: Begin by creating an initialization function within your shared module to set up Koin with
your application modules.
fun initKoin(appDeclaration: KoinAppDeclaration) = startKoin {
    modules(sharedModules())
    appDeclaration()
}

Configure Android Context: In your Android Application class, invoke initKoin and incorporate androidContext to pass the context seamlessly.
initKoin {
       androidContext(this@MainApplication)
       // Add additional Android-specific modules here.
}

Cross-Platform SQL Driver Module Configuration:
Declare Expect Variable: Establish an expect variable in your common module to define the SQL driver module.
expect val sqlDriverModule: Module

Android Implementation: Define the actual SQL driver module for Android, utilizing AndroidSqliteDriver for database operations.
actual val sqlDriverModule: Module = module {
      single<SqlDriver> {
           AndroidSqliteDriver(
              schema = DataBaseName.Schema,
              context = get(),
              name = "DataBaseName.db"
           )
      }
}

iOS Implementation: Similarly, specify the actual SQL driver module for iOS, employing NativeSqliteDriver.
actual val sqlDriverModule: Module = module {
        single {
            NativeSqliteDriver(DataBaseName.Schema, "DataBaseName.db")
        }
}

Final Step: ensure the sqlDriverModule is included in your sharedModules() within the shared module.

Didn't work...
org.koin.core.error.KoinAppAlreadyStartedException: A Koin Application has already been started

ok wait. this works if I run Koin from Android application, which will not show this error and will make the app work. but what about other platforms?
this requires me to change the code each time i need to run a different platform right?

It seems I can solve this by starting Koin from each platform and not from the shared!
